# Changing Theme in Android (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, background

I made 4 buttons.Each button has the ability to change the background color to a different color using the something.changeToTheme(this, something.BLACK);.It works fine but after I close the app and restart it the theme is always set to default.Is there a way to save the background from the previous session and view that when I reopen the app?

Comment: use shared preferances

Comment: Can you give me a basic example?

Comment: Share some code please, atleast your button's code

Comment: this link will help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Use persistent storage for storing the current theme before closing the application. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) out.

Comment: See updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `switch` to:

```
switch (cTheme)
{
    case BLACK:         
        int myTheme = R.style.Default
        activity.setTheme(myTheme);

        //Save your activity theme color
        saveTheme(myTheme);
    break;

    case YELLOW:
        int myTheme = R.style.Green
        activity.setTheme(myTheme);

        //Save your activity theme color
        saveTheme(myTheme);
    break;
}
```

and change your `onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)` to:

```
public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity, Int cTheme)
```

**Save method**

```
public void saveTheme(int theme)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    prefEditor.putInt("Theme",theme); 
}
```

**Load method**

```
public int loadTheme(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    //Load theme color
    int theme = sharedPreferences.getInt("Theme",Color.RED); //RED is default color, when nothing is saved yet

    return theme;
}
```

**Important:** call `loadTheme()` **before** `setContentView()` so your `onCreate()` should be like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  int theme = loadTheme();        //Load your theme here!!!!
  CustomazationProcess.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, theme);
  setContentView(R.layout.something1);

  findViewById(R.id.black).setOnClickListener(this);
  findViewById(R.id.yellow).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Hope this helps u out

Comment: I just updated my question with code,do you think it will work with mine?Can you help me implement it in mine?

Comment: What do u want to change? button background colors? or your activity background color?

Comment: activity background color

Comment: Ok, I will see what I can do

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This should work, but I don't have access to android studio at the moment, so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out now

Comment: I am getting some errors mainly with  prefEditor.putInt("Theme",theme); (Cannot resolve symbol) and with SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Should work, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112769/save-android-theme-using-shared-preferences)

Comment: No luck yet.Can you sent me a message back when you get the chance to test it yourself if you can?Sorry for that I am not very experienced yet.

Comment: Fixed it.Thanks for the help.