# Is there a method to change font style,color in Android Preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have created custom preferences into my app, which uses SharedPreferences to save data and I used PreferenceActivity.

Now I need to modify its appearance. Including font style, color, and font type. If possible, add custom colors, background, add images, etc.

Can I do that? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Create your own style.

Comment: how?im kinda new to this.so could you help little more?

Comment: Start by googling `android custom style`

Comment: please show this. it is help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112769/save-android-theme-using-shared-preferences

Answer (score 1):

Start off by creating a custom style whose parent is the app's theme.
**styles.xml**

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/whatever</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then, in your Settings class,

(if it extends PreferenceFragment, then do this in the onCreateView)

```
container.getContext().setTheme(R.style.PreferenceTheme);
```

(otherwise, if it extends PreferenceActivity, then do this in onCreate)

```
setTheme(R.style.PreferenceTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you create extend TextView class and create custom Typeface.
Then go to style folder and create new style and set color and size there.