# How to save a theme using a package Shared_Preferences

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

Help me figure out where to write something in the code so that the theme is saved after restarting the application...
Installed the [animated_theme_switcher](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_theme_switcher) package and I can't figure out where to prescribe so that the theme is preserved

my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final isPlatformDark = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
final theme = isPlatformDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme;

child: ThemeProvider(
        initTheme: theme,
        builder: (context, theme) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: theme,
            home: MyApp1(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          );
        },
      ),
```

And the action on the button

```
                                       onPressed: () async {
                                          var brightness =
                                              ThemeProvider.of(context)!.brightness;
                                          ThemeSwitcher.of(context)!.changeTheme(
                                            theme: brightness == Brightness.light
                                                ? darkTheme
                                                : lightTheme,
                                            reverseAnimation:
                                            brightness == Brightness.dark
                                                ? true
                                                : false,
                                          );
                                          setState(() {
                                            toggle = !toggle;
                                          });
                                        },
```

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112769/save-android-theme-using-shared-preferences ?

Comment: not quite understood everything .. confusing (

Answer (score 0):

Try using adaptive_theme,
Adaptive_theme: https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_theme